# How do I detect, with JavaScript, if an image was pasted or dropped into a contenteditable area?

Tags: javascript, image, alert, clipboard

I have a script that prevents the user from pasting, or dropping dragged images into a contenteditable area. When the user tries to do one of those two things, I want an alert to tell him he cannot do that. I tried adding `alert("custom message")` right before the last break. But it gets triggered in both cases (pasting and dropping). How can I have two different alerts: one for when the user pastes an image ("you cannot paste images here"), and another for when the user drops a dragged image ("you cannot drop images here", within my code?

https://jsfiddle.net/36cfdpoh/

```js
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("editDiv").oninput = function() {
        var thisElement = this;
        var currentElementChildren, currentElementChildrenLength;
        var elements = this.children;
        var elementsLength = elements.length;
        if (elementsLength > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < elementsLength; i++) {
                if (elements[i].tagName == "IMG") {
                    thisElement.children[i].remove();
                    break;
                } else {
                    currentElementChildren = elements[i].children;
                    currentElementChildrenLength = currentElementChildren.length;
                    if (currentElementChildrenLength > 0) {
                        for (ii = 0; ii < currentElementChildrenLength; ii++) {
                            if (currentElementChildren[ii].tagName == "IMG") {
                                thisElement.children[i].children[ii].remove();
                                alert("you cannot drop images here");
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
#editDiv {
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }

img {
    width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div id="editDiv" contenteditable="true">
    <p>Try to drop or paste that image here.</p>
</div>
    
<img src="https://i7.pngguru.com/preview/134/138/533/star-golden-stars.jpg">
```

Comment: Your script has 2 problems. First, if the user `drop` or `paste` more than one image, only one image will be removed. Second, you only check the children and children of children so if the images were dropped or pasted in a deeply nested element, for example, a `p` element in another `div` element the images won't be removed at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solutions to this. Using the `input` event or using `drop` and `paste` events:

`index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <title>Image phobia</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Image phobia</h1>

  <div id="editDiv" contenteditable="true">
    <p>Try to drop or paste that image here.</p>
  </div>

  <img height="100" width="100" src="https://i7.pngguru.com/preview/134/138/533/star-golden-stars.jpg">
  <img height="100" width="100" src="https://i7.pngguru.com/preview/134/138/533/star-golden-stars.jpg">

  <script src="main.js" />
</body>

</html>
```

`input` event solution:

`main.js`

```js
"use strict";
(function() {
  window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    const editDiv = document.getElementById("editDiv");

    // return a message depending on input type
    function alertMessage(type) {
      switch (type) {
        case "insertFromPaste":
          return "You can't paste images here";
        case "insertFromDrop":
          return "You can't drop images here";
      }
    }

    // recursive function to delete image from an element's children
    function removeImages(children) {
      let hadImage = false;
      for (let i = children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        const child = children[i];
        if (child.tagName === "IMG") {
          child.remove();
          hadImage = true;
          continue;
        }
        if (child.children.length) {
          hadImage = removeImages(child.children);
          if (hadImage) {
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      return hadImage;
    }

    function preventImageInput(e) {
      const inputType = e.inputType;
      if (inputType === "insertFromDrop" || inputType === "insertFromPaste") {
        if (e.target.children.length) {
          const hadImage = removeImages(e.target.children);
          if (hadImage) {
            alert(alertMessage(inputType));
          }
        }
      }
    }

    editDiv.addEventListener("input", preventImageInput);
  });
})();
```

`drop` and `paste` events solution:

`main.js`

```js
"use strict";
(function() {
  window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    const editDiv = document.getElementById("editDiv");

    // return message depending on event type
    function alertMessage(type) {
      switch (type) {
        case "paste":
          return "You can't paste images here";
        case "drop":
          return "You can't drop images here";
      }
    }

    function preventImageInput(e) {
      // you must use setTimeout because when both the paste or drop events are fired
      // the content isn't changed yet and you won't have access to the new content
      setTimeout(() => {
        const images = e.target.querySelectorAll("img");
        if (images.length) {
          for (let i = images.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            const image = images[i];
            image.remove();
          }
          alert(alertMessage(e.type));
        }
      });
    }

    editDiv.addEventListener("paste", preventImageInput);
    editDiv.addEventListener("drop", preventImageInput);
  });
})();
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! Just before I mark your answer as correct, could you just edit it to tell which of the two solutions would you recommend, and why? It will be useful both for me and for other people who might check this out.

Comment: Also, if I wanted to call a function in each case, instead of triggering an alert, how would I do that? I tried something like ´case "drop": myFunction(); break;´ instead of ´return "You can't drop images here"´. It does call the function, but is still triggering an empty alert.

Comment: I would use the `input` event version because using `setTimeout` like that is sort of a hack. just change 
`case "insertFromPaste": return "You can't paste images here";` to 
`case "insertFromPaste": myFunction(); break;` and you better change the function name from `alertMessage` to `onImageRemoved` then instead of calling it like so `alert(alertMessage(inputType))` just call it without the `alert` function like so `onImageRemoved(inputType)`.

Comment: That works, thanks! How about if I wanted to call a function if it was text being pasted/dropped and not images? How should I do it?

Comment: The default browser behavior: only text selections, images, and links can be dragged. In the `input` version in `preventImageInput` function if `hadImage` is false then the added content was link or text and you can call your other function. In the `paste` and `drop` version in `preventImageInput` function if `images.length` is `0` then the added content is link or text and you can call your other function.

Comment: The default browser behavior: only text selections, images, and links can be dragged. In the `input` version in `preventImageInput` function if `hadImage` is false then the added content was link or text and you can call your other function. In the `paste` and `drop` version in `preventImageInput` function if `images.length` is `0` then the added content is link or text and you can call your other function.

Answer (score 2):

You can separately attach [paste](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event) & [drop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/drop_event) event to dom and then check which one is firing

Comment: And how would I be able to tell which kind of content was pasted/dropped? I don't want to do anything when it's text. Just images.